# Copy source backup folder contents to a folder where the name is the local date

Tags: backup, powershell

I'm needing to move only the contents (files and subfolders) of a folder located in:

\\serverA\critical\

to a new folder where the name must be the local date in:

\\serverB\dd-mm-yyyy

and then clear all the contents of \serverA\critical\

How can I do that in powershell ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It could be rather difficult if you create each folder as a separate share, you will have tou use WMI calls in order to achevie the goal.

But if you palce your critical fodler to the parent share, it could siginificantly simplify the issue.

Check out my powershell example below:

```
`$sourceparent = "\\serverA\parentshare\"
$destinationparent = "\\serverB\parentshare\"
$source = "critical"
$destination = $destinationparent + (Get-Date -format d).ToString()
cd $parent
try{
    Write-Host "Copying from source to destination"
    Copy-Item $source $destination -Recurse
}
catch{
    Write-Host "Unable to copy, deletion cancelled"
    break
}
finally{
    Write-Host "Copy finisehd, deleting source files"
    Remove-Item ($source + "\*")
}`
```

It will grab everything in \\ServerA\parentshare\critical and copy to \\ServerB\parentshare\29-Jan-16 . After the operation finished, everything in \\ServerA\parentshare\critical will be deleted.

If you have more quesitons, pelase let me know.

Regards,
Vlad,
CloudBerry Lab